# How to pass multiple JPEG images to convert through pipe?

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn
var fs = require('fs')
var Readable = require('stream').Readable

var stream = new Readable()
var img1 = fs.readFileSync('img1.jpg')
var img2 = fs.readFileSync('img2.jpg')
stream.push(img1)
stream.push(img2)
stream.push(null)
var convert = spawn('convert', ['jpg:fd:0', 'out.gif'])
stream.pipe(convert.stdio[0])
```

throws

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: write EPIPE
    at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
    at Object.afterWrite (net.js:721:19)
```

But it works when I push just one image to pipe. So it seems that convert don't now that I am passing multiple images through a stream and it just closes the pipe after first image is received... Is it possible to pass many JPEG images to convert through pipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPEG isn't a *"streaming"* format for ImageMagick, which means you cannot simply concatenate multiple JPEG files together and expect `ImageMagick` to sort them out. The only streaming format is `MIFF`, so you would have to concatenate the files together as a MIFF stream and into `ImageMagick` from there.

This may clarify... I convert `page0.gif` to `MIFF` and send it to `stdout`, then  convert `page1.gif` to `MIFF` and append that to the output stream. Then I start a new `convert` and read in the two files from the combined `MIFF` stream and make 2 GIF files out of them:

```
{ convert page0.gif miff:- ; convert page1.gif miff:- ; } | convert miff:- out-%d.gif

-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff   10383 24 Sep 16:29 out-1.gif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff   11778 24 Sep 16:29 out-0.gif
```

Or you could send one JPEG on one stream and another JPEG on another stream and tell `ImageMgick` to read from one then the other, i.e.:

```
convert fd:0 fd:1 out.gif
```

Also, what are you expecting `ImageMagick` to do with the two files? Do you want them appended side-by-side? Or appended one above the other? Or written to two separate files? Your intentions are not too clear.

If you want to make an animated GIF out of them, you should do the node.js equivalent of:

```
{ convert page0.gif miff:- ; convert page1.gif miff:- ; } | convert miff:- -delay 100 out.gif
```

Comment: I want to create animated gif from images that I have in-memory. I thought it can work like in FFMPEG where I can just pass multiple JPEG images in single stream and get video as output...

Comment: Ok, see my update at the bottom - you need to add in a `-delay`.

Comment: Well I still would have to spawn N process to convert JPEGs to MIFFs and another one to concat them to gif and it would be very slow. Anyway I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

By default end() is called on the destination when the source stream emits end, so that destination is no longer writable. Pass { end: false } as options to keep the destination stream open.

```
image1Stream.pipe(writer, { end: false });
image2Stream.pipe(writer);
```